# assign values to variables in python3, only last set is assigned to all

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, cs50

i have tried to assign each variable the set values that have the words that are of the proper length. if I print it out the single steps seem fine but when I try to see what is inside I get the last set built.

```
to_add = set()

 for x in self.domains:

     to_add.clear() # clear set for next search

     for word in self.domains[x]:

         if len(word) == (x.length):

             to_add.add(word)

     self.domains[x] = to_add

     for variable in self.crossword.variables:

         if variable == x:

             self.crossword.values = self.domains[x]

             variable = to_add

             print ("")

             print ("***************")

             print (x)

             print (self.crossword.values)

             print (variable)

             print ("***************")

 print("-----------------")

 print (self.domains)

 print("-----------------")
```

as an example of the error that I get (i get that each of the six variables all have the same values even though they are not the same):

```
(4, 4) across : 5 {'DEPTH', 'INFER', 'GRAPH', 'ALPHA', 'FALSE', 'LOGIC', 'PRUNE', 'BAYES', 'TRUTH', 'START'} {'DEPTH', 'INFER', 'GRAPH', 'ALPHA', 'FALSE', 'LOGIC', 'PRUNE', 'BAYES', 'TRUTH', 'START'}

(6, 5) across : 6 {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'} {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}

{Variable(2, 1, 'down', 5): {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}, Variable(1, 7, 'down', 7): {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}, Variable(1, 12, 'down', 7): {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}, Variable(2, 1, 'across', 12): {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}, Variable(4, 4, 'across', 5): {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}, Variable(6, 5, 'across', 6): {'SEARCH', 'NEURAL', 'REASON', 'MARKOV', 'CREATE'}}
```

Can anyone give me an idea of how I can fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're adding and clearing the *same set* repeatedly.

`self.domains[x] = to_add` doesn't add a copy to `domains`, so every time you modify `to_add`, you're also modifying what's already been added to `domains`, because they're all the same set.

The simplest solution would be to create a new `to_add` set once per iteration:

```
for x in self.domains:

    # Create a new set each time instead of clearing the old one
    to_add = set()  

    for word in self.domains[x]:
        . . .
```